# Execute SQL Server stored procedures sequentially with notification

Tags: sql, sql-server

For Microsoft SQL server, I would like to execute stored procedures sequentially, with notification and using results when later parts of procedures are still executing. For example, the below code would print the 3 sentences, 'Update_TableX_done' only after all 3 procedures are completed.

'Update_TableX' are stored procedures that would insert some updated data into in a table.

Can I set such that Print is performed after each EXEC statement completed?

Can I use result of Table1 when Table2 is updating?

Can I keep the result of Update_Table1, if the process of Update_Table2 fails?

Or, is the only solution to manually start Update_Table2 only after Update_Table1 is finished?

```
    EXEC [dbo].[Update_Table1]
    PRINT 'Update_Table1_done'
    EXEC [dbo].[Update_Table2]
    PRINT 'Update_Table2_done'
    EXEC [dbo].[Update_Table3]
    PRINT 'Update_Table3_done'
```

Comment: SQL is a sequential language when running a batch; each statement in the batch is run in turn, one after the next. You have 6 statements there, and each will be run after the previous (top-down); one won't run until the other completes (that doesn't mean successfully). Yes, you can use the output of a `UPDATE`, but what you have there are `EXEC` statements, not `UPDATE` statements. You don't, however, define what you want to actually do here. Take a step back, and look at your question and see if you could answer it with the vague info we have. you need to be clearer on what you're asking.

Comment: Per your suggestion, added the sentence to clarify they are stored procedures: 'Update_TableX' are stored procedures that would insert some updated data into in a table.

Comment: Question one: yes, question 2 and 3: cant tell without more info what you are trying to do

Comment: Question 1: yes (Can you share your SQL code? or system setting? Currently my system pop up 3 print statements only after the whole query finish.)

Comment: Question 2 and 3: It is a query to insert new rows in a table, based on information in another table periodically updated by another user.

Answer (score 1):

PRINT command flushes messages when a buffer is filled. To trigger immediate message flush to Message stream use RAISEERROR with WITH NOWAIT option.

```
raiserror('Test 1', 10, 1) with nowait;
waitfor delay '00:00:05';
raiserror('Test 2', 10, 1) with nowait;
```